# One data row that spans multiple DataGridView lines

Tags: winforms, datagridview

In Winforms, is there a way to have a single DataGridView row span multiple lines?  So that the cells of a single row can be stacked onto two lines.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: I think this will help you. I got the same requirement and it solve it...Link [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/Multi_Column_Combo_Cell.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "simple" way to do this is with custom painting. It still isn't entirely trivial however, and you do not get editable cells this way.

Any solution to give editable cells would require a lot of custom code.

Quoting the DataGridView Program Manager Mark Rideout from a [forum discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/fea3dcff-5447-450a-8f7c-bb1c4f63371d/):

> The DataGridView does not have any
>   support for merging cells. You can
>   custom paint content across cells, but
>   apart from that you would have to do a
>   lot of work and custom coding to
>   produce merged editable cells.

That forum does contain some example code of custom painting if that will do for your requirement.

Comment: thanks for the word.  One more argument in favor of buying a more sophisticated grid.